# plot histogram where each bin is greater or equal to an incremented value

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Hi I am using ggplot to plot a histogram (actually using the geom_bar function), but instead of having each bin defining as a unique range, is it possible to define each bin as >= a certain value. i.e. first bin >= 1 second bin >= 2 etc etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a Cumulative Distribution Function be more natural for that?

```
x <- rexp(1000)
hist(x)
plot(ecdf(x))
```

[image: histogram and ECDF plots]

The bottom plot is a CDF, and you can read off the cumulative totals there.  Approximately 60% of the values are >=1.  Approximately 85% of the values are >= 2.  You could replace the y-axis labels of the normal CDF to use the normal absolute count values instead of the percentages.